# D*アルゴリズムの概略

Tags: アルゴリズム

Dスターアルゴリズム経路詮索のうちどれに分類されますか

- 深さ優先探索
- 幅優先探索
- 最良優先探索

アルゴリズムに関する擬似コードのようなものは知られていますか

---

追記
A*とくらべD*は評価関数が１つまたは、２つ追加されているようですが
その１つ又は、２つの関数の目的は？

Answer (score 3):

最良優先検索にカテゴライズされます。
経路のコストが動的に変わる場合に使えるA*みたいなものです。

英語ですが
http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~motionplanning/lecture/AppH-astar-dstar_howie.pdf
こういうスライドがありますのでご参照ください。

Comment: 経路のコストが動的に変わるとは、探索中もしくは移動中に最良の枝・ルート・コストの値が変わるということですか